# Exception in thread "main" client.exception.EosApiException: Not Found: unspecified while creating account

Tags: eosio.token, testnet, account-creation

I am using following of Java code while creating account:

- Using Java library

> - eos-java-rpc-wrapper
> - adyliu/jeos

- Using

> Jungle2 testnet

- Chain Id of jungle2 testnet:

> 038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca

The Following java code

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import client.EosApiClientFactory;
import client.EosApiRestClient;
import client.domain.common.transaction.PackedTransaction;
import client.domain.common.transaction.SignedPackedTransaction;
import client.domain.common.transaction.TransactionAction;
import client.domain.common.transaction.TransactionAuthorization;
import client.domain.response.chain.AbiJsonToBin;
import client.domain.response.chain.Block;
import client.domain.response.chain.transaction.PushedTransaction;


public class CreateAccount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        EosApiRestClient eosApiRestClient = EosApiClientFactory.newInstance("http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:8888").newRestClient();

        /* Create the json array of arguments */
        Map<String, String> args1 = new HashMap<>(4);
        args1.put("from", "abontester12"); // SENDER (MY PRE-GENERATED EOS ACCOUNT)
        args1.put("to", "eosio"); // RECEIVER
        args1.put("quantity", "0.1000 EOS"); // AMOUNT
        args1.put("memo", "My First Transaction"); // JUST MEMO
        AbiJsonToBin data = eosApiRestClient.abiJsonToBin("eosio.token", "transfer", args1);

        System.out.println("data::"+ data.getBinargs());

        Block block = eosApiRestClient.getBlock(eosApiRestClient.getChainInfo().getHeadBlockId());

        System.out.println("block::"+ block.getId());

        /* Create Transaction Action Authorization */
        TransactionAuthorization transactionAuthorization = new TransactionAuthorization();
        transactionAuthorization.setActor("abontester12");
        transactionAuthorization.setPermission("active");

        /* Create Transaction Action */
        TransactionAction transactionAction = new TransactionAction();
        transactionAction.setAccount("abontester12");
        transactionAction.setName("transfer");
        transactionAction.setData(data.getBinargs());
        transactionAction.setAuthorization(Collections.singletonList(transactionAuthorization));

        /* Create a transaction */
        PackedTransaction packedTransaction = new PackedTransaction();
        packedTransaction.setRefBlockPrefix(block.getRefBlockPrefix().toString());
        packedTransaction.setRefBlockNum(block.getBlockNum().toString());
        packedTransaction.setExpiration("2019-04-30T14:53:59.000");
        packedTransaction.setRegion("0");
        packedTransaction.setMax_net_usage_words("0");
        packedTransaction.setContextFreeData(Collections.emptyList());
        packedTransaction.setContextFreeActions(Collections.emptyList());
        packedTransaction.setActions(Collections.singletonList(transactionAction));

        SignedPackedTransaction signedPackedTransaction = eosApiRestClient.signTransaction(packedTransaction, Collections.singletonList("EOS6t8Piaew17krZSMM3aZJt6XMawH9HuvDZPABw7kooJRTiUeijD"),"038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca");

        /* Push the transaction */
       // PushedTransaction = eosApiRestClient.pushTransaction("none", signedPackedTransaction);

        PushedTransaction pushedTransaction = eosApiRestClient.pushTransaction("none", signedPackedTransaction);
        System.out.println("pushedTransaction=" + pushedTransaction.getTransactionId());


    }
}
```

**It gives the following Exception:**

```
INFO: {"code":404,"message":"Not Found","error":{"code":0,"name":"exception","what":"unspecified","details":[{"message":"Unknown Endpoint","file":"http_plugin.cpp","line_number":328,"method":"handle_http_request"}]}}
Apr 24, 2019 3:53:08 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <-- END HTTP (210-byte body)
Exception in thread "main" client.exception.EosApiException: Not Found: unspecified
    at client.impl.EosApiServiceGenerator.executeSync(EosApiServiceGenerator.java:55)
    at client.impl.EosApiRestClientImpl.signTransaction(EosApiRestClientImpl.java:197)
    at com.apiservice.controller.CreateAccount.main(CreateAccount.java:61)
```

**pom.xml is:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>jeos</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.EOSEssentials</groupId>
    <artifactId>eos-java-rpc-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

even tried with chain id for testnet at suggested

```
chain id : e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473
```

Comment: Jungle2 is discontinued. Use Jungle3.

Answer (score 0):

Chain-ID of jungle2 is

> e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473

Comment: also tried with the same having same error even have accountname "abontester12" on testnet  **it returns message**  _INFO: {"code":404,"message":"Not Found","error":{"code":0,"name":"exception","what":"unspecified","details":[{"message":"Unknown Endpoint","file":"http_plugin.cpp","line_number":328,"method":"handle_http_request"}]}}_

Answer (score 0):

Your Testnet-URL seems to be wrong.

Try one of these Endpoints or get an updated list [here](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#apiendpoints).

```
http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80
https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443
https://jungle.eosio.cr:443
https://api.jungle.alohaeos.com:443
http://145.239.133.201:8888
http://jungle2.eosdac.io:8882
https://jungle.eosn.io:443
https://eos-jungle.eosblocksmith.io:443
http://jungle2-eos.blckchnd.com:8888
http://88.99.193.44:8888
https://jungleapi.eossweden.se:443
https://jungle.eosphere.io:443
http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:8888
http://88.99.193.44:8888
http://jungle.eosamsterdam.net:80
http://95.179.186.107:8888
http://85.214.108.53:8888
http://42.159.153.121:8888
http://121.168.149.101:8888
https://testnet-api.eosarabia.one:443
http://88.12.21.79:8888
```

This line should be updated. I also used the **https** endpoint.

```
EosApiRestClient eosApiRestClient = EosApiClientFactory.newInstance("https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443").newRestClient();
```

Comment: it gives me the same error ..........what will be the chain id for this test net point

Comment: INFO: <-- 404 Not Found http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:8888/v1/wallet/sign_transaction (233ms)